# Pull information from wget data

Tags: bash, twitter

I want to pull and display the twitter username of various accounts that I specify via the ID. I figured I could do this, in part, with wget.

```
echo what id would you like to search
read ID 
wget https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=$ID > ~/temp/$ID
```

This is really as far as I got as I cant figure out how to pull the data from it. I have tried this;

```
read ID
source ~/temp/$ID
echo $value
```

To echo anything that was labeled as "value" (the username is labeled as "value" several times).

Examples:
Stack Overflow's Twitter account is @stackoverflow, and their twitter id is: 128700677 So I can run

```
wget https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=128700677
```

and the document will be a nice 248 line long HTML document, you can try it and see. So basically, is there a way to have the script either go through and find the most common value="" or just go to/display `<title>Stack Overflow (@StackOverflow) on Twitter</title>` without the `<title></title>` and `on Twitter`

PS: Would this count as bootstrapping?

EDIT-----------------------------
This needs to be able to work with bash because I already have a system set up in bash. This will just help confirm @s

Comment: Use [the twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) to get well defined json

Comment: I dont know how to use the api at all and i already have an entire bash script written up. This would just help for the clarity of the viewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As that-other-guy said, it would be better to use twitter API to find that out. However, you can try and push your method a little bit further, like

```
wget -O - "https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=${ID}" | grep -Po "(?<=screen_name=).*(?=')" | head -n 1
```

to filter out strings like `href='/intent/user?screen_name=StackOverflow'` and extract what's after `screen_name=` part in the first string.

P.S. I didn't notice a lot of `value=` in the html, to be honest, and sourcing something like html in your script is not the best thing to do, as you may get something destructive executing this way.

Answer (score 1):

`screen_name` could be fetched with:

```
 read -r ID ;\
 screen_name=$(wget -q -O - http://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id="$ID" |  sed -n 's/^.*button follow".*screen_name=\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/p')
 printf "%s\n" "$screen_name"
```

`nickname` could be fetched with:

```
read -r ID ;\
nickname=$(wget -q -O - https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=128700677 | sed -n 's/^.*"nickname">\([^<]*\)<.*$/\1/p')
printf "%s\n" "$nickname"
```

`title` could be fetched with:

```
read -r ID ;\
title=$(wget -q -O - https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=128700677 | sed -n 's/^.*<title>\(.*\) on Twitter<.title>.*$/\1/p')
printf "%s\n" "$title"
```

The use of the REST API sounds a better idea.